# Android layout parameters fill_parent doesn't have any affect

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

I have a problem that when I set a layout xml file on an activity with width & height = fill_parent and set a background color as, say, grey, i do not get any background color when I start the activity.
I tried creating a custom layout which extends LinearLayout and when I call onMeasure at this custom layout, i get

> onMeasure: -2147483048 | -2147482761

where horizontal space requirements : -2147483048
and vertical space requirements : -2147482761

So, when I use

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

for my custom layout, i get nothing, but when i use for example

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,
            50));
```

then i get a rectangle

My question is, why?

EDIT: Tested on real phones and emulators

EDIT2:
xml:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

EDIT3:
java:

```
onCreate:
        setContentView(new CustomAlarmLayout(this));
```

or

```
onCreate:
setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
```

EDIT4:
The number is equal MeasureSpec.AT_MOST

trying to set it to MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED doesn't change anything, the view is still not resized when onMeasure is called

EDIT5:
My bad. The problem was that there was a wrap_content set on the TabWidget common area, so that is why my fill_parent wouldn't work

Comment: Add xml please. Btw use match_parent, as fill_parent is deprecated as of API level 8

Comment: What is going on about the downvotes??? this is a valid question, and I am tired of seeing downvotes everywhere just because some smart ass doesn't like the way a question is being asked or anything else... this is a great community with some really stupid members sometimes..

Comment: @Perroloco there are rules about how you ask a question)

Comment: Please post onCreate() method and xml please. And with xml I don't mean a single line of xml with a correct syntax. How are we supposed to help if you only give single lines of code?

Comment: because that is all i've got except for the default parts of application

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?? You must be doing something wrong either in your layout xml or your activity.

Try using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#FF0000">
</LinearLayout>
```

You should get a red background

Comment: orientation is out of importance here

Comment: please post your activity's oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want insert this layout (and its setting) in runcode...why you don´t try include in the .xml file of this activity a relative or linear layout setting by default the params widht and height as a MATCH_PARENT or FILL_PARENT. After this, insert your linearlayout by runcode inside of that layout inn the .xml.

Something like that:

```
myGenericLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
myGenericLayout.addView ( "your layout with the setting that you want here" );
```

Comment: Is better use MATCH_PARENT instead of FILL_PARENT

Comment: i do the same from the custom view - doesn't help